# to use img tag in fieldset

Tags: jquery

```
    var i = 1;
function radio_slide(){
    var nameval="'radio_ans_"+i+"'";
    var clsval="'field_"+i+"'";
    var radio = '<fieldset class="field_'+i+'"><table><tr><td class="main_index"><img src="a_forms/a.jpg" /><b>'+i+'. </b><select style="width: 73%;" name="radioslide_'+i+'" id=""><option value="'+i+'" selected="selected">Radio</option></select></td><td><input type="button" name="radio_ans" onclick="add_new_ans('+nameval+');" class="ans"  value=" Answer"></td><td><input type="button" name="field_'+i+'" onclick="delete('+clsval+')" class="delete_ans"  value="Question"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="radio_question_name_'+i+'" placeholder="Question"></td><td><input type="text" name="radio_ques_rad_name_'+i+'" placeholder="Field Name"></td></td></tr><tr><th>Answer</th><th>Value</th><th>Image</th></tr><tr class="ans"><td class="index"><b>1. </b><input type="text" name="radio_answer_name_'+i+'_1" placeholder="Answer"></td><td><input type="text" name="radio_answer_value_'+i+'_1" placeholder="Value"></td><td><input type="file" class="browse_file"  name="radio_answer_image_'+i+'_1"></td></tr><tr class="ans"><td class="index"><b>2. </b><input type="text" name="radio_answer_name_'+i+'_2" placeholder="Answer"></td><td><input type="text" name="radio_answer_value_'+i+'_2" placeholder="Value"></td><td><input type="file" class="browse_file"  name="radio_answer_image_'+i+'_2"></td></tr><tr class="radio_ans_'+i+'"><td colspan=3><input style="width:100%" type="text" name="ques_desc_'+i+'" placeholder="Question Description"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=3><input style="width:100%" type="text" name="ques_footer_'+i+'" placeholder="Question Footer"></td></tr></table><input type="hidden" name="radio-total-ans-'+i+'" class="radio_ans_total_'+i+'" value="2"/></fieldset>';
    $("#frm").append(radio);
    i = i+1;
 }in actual i have this code img src is visible to me
```

when i am using this img tag in td it does not pic the img can someone please help me what is the actual syntax.. src=""???

Comment: you have properly ended the string for radio variable, put `'` at the end

Comment: What has this got to do with PHP?

Comment: ok bt the actual problm is with img tag...

Comment: Well, Bhushan is right: nothing will ever happen, unless you put a `'` (and maybe an `;`) at the end of your `radio` string and even then you will only have declared this variable. Nothing will *show* on the page as yet. Some *action* seems to be missing.

Comment: in actual this is the function.. i want the img to be visible used in td bt the image is not visible may be the problem is in src ???

Comment: So, basically everything but the `img` tag seems to work, yes? The `img` tag seems OK to me from the syntax point of view ... it includes a *relative*  reference, so make sure you got it right.

Comment: You need to check the image path first by putting `img` tag directly into your html and see if image is coming or not. Correct your path and then try the same with function. And also make sure that your table or td element is not having `display:none;`

Comment: yes i got you but i dont know why image is not visible

Comment: the problem is with src="" ... the img taking width and height which i gve in style tag i.e width :30px and height:30px